# Remote debug safari ios9 and MacOs 10.13

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios9

I have an old iphone 4s with iOS9. I checked Settings > Safari > Advanced : Web Inspector on the device and enabled Safari > Preferences > Advanced : Show Develop on the Mac.

When I connect the phone and browse with safari, the iphone doesn't appear in the Develop menu.

The process works fine with an ipad iOS 11 (I can access the debug console via the Develop menu).

Anyone has an idear on this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Apple this usually means that you should update Safari to the latest version. Well, you better upgrade everything with Apple. Sometimes they break and fix things.

Another thing you could try is to reset the PRAM and SMC that often solve Mac hardware problems : 
http://osxdaily.com/2010/03/24/when-and-how-to-reset-your-mac-system-management-controller-smc/

And last, check that you have enabled web inspector on the said iphone. Sometimes we forget the very basic thing or it might have been turned off by something.

Some people with the same problem solved it by using Safari Technology Preview: https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

Comment: I reset the PRAM and SMC with no luck. I checked the Web Inspector and it's enabled. As I work on a Macbook Pro mi 2010 (I know...) I can't use Safari Technology Preview. So I think I can't solve this one. But I tried on another Mac, Macbook Air (mid 2012) with MacOx 10.12 and I can see the iphone in the Develop menu. So I have a way to continue my work. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: You’re welcome. I feared it was related to that issue. Sadly “old” hardware is always abandoned at some point.

Comment: I was also able to debug this without an issue on an older Macbook Air (circa 2014).